# Prove that for all $\alpha\in\textbf{On}$ the set $V_{\alpha}$ is transitive

Tags: set-theory

Im  a little stuck here. I'm thinking of doing induction on the ordinals $\textbf{On}$, but I can't make it work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathscr{P}(V_\beta)$.

Induction: Assume $V_\beta$ is transitive for all $\beta<\alpha$.

Lemma 1. If $X$ is transitive, then $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is transitive.

Lemma 2. The union of transitive sets is transitive.

Comment: ah okay, i think i got it.
And $V_0=\emptyset$, sot its trivail? for the indtuction start?